# How to transfer PS4 game files from an old internal drive to a new one (bigger one)

Tags: ps4, hard-drive

I bought a 500GB PS4 and 500GB just isn't enough so I was planning upgrade my internal storage with a 2TB DRIVE. A lot of my games are digital and after doing a lot of research, I found out that backing up that digital data and restoring it on another drive, might be a problem and I might have to redownload all my games again which I really wish not to do. Is there a way I could say back up all my data onto a drive and then swap the 500 GB drive with the 2TB and then restore my data onto the 2TB now in the console?
I am asking ahead just to know because if it's not possible, I'd just use the bigger drive as an external extended storage or something. But if it's possible, that'd be great.

Comment: The backup/restore features on the PS4 should allow you to do just this. Be warned that it is a slow process. It is now possible to use an external drive as extended storage but the external drive (USB) must be plugged directly into the console. You cannot use a USB hub except for backup and restore.. There are instructions for both methods on the playsation support website. .

Answer (score 1):

I've done this plenty of times using the PS4's backup and restore utility with absolutely no problems. It does warn you that some games may not work, but I haven't run across this yet. IIRC trophies are the only thing that aren't transferred, but that's why they tell you to sync your trophies online first. It is a slow process though.

As pew noted as a comment, a recent PS4 update allows you to attach a drive via USB as extended storage. You can run games off the extended storage without issue.